# RStudio / Shiny: radioButtons' List

Tags: r, radio-button, rstudio

I am developing an app and, when choosing the country, I want the user to either select it from a list (selectInput) or introduce the coordinates (numericInput). I have tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
 radioButtons("country", "Choose:",
         list(
           conditionalPanel(
             condition="input.species=='Cc'",
             selectInput("country", "Country",
               choices=subset(NestingArea, Sp=="Cc")$Country)),
           numericInput(
             inputId="latitude",
             label="Latitude:",
             value=00, min=-90, max=90, step=1)))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can embed inputs as options in your radioButton list. You can, however, show different inputs based on the user's choices to other inputs:

```
radioButtons("choice", "Choose:", choices = c("By Country", "By Coordinates")),
conditionalPanel("input.choice == 'By Country'",
                 selectInput("country", "Country",
                              choices=c("A", "B", "C")
                 )
),
conditionalPanel("input.choice == 'By Coordinates'",
                 numericInput(
                   inputId="latitude",
                   label="Latitude:",
                   value=00, min=-90, max=90, step=1
                 ),
                 numericInput(
                   inputId="longitude",
                   label="Longitude:",
                   value=00, min=-360, max=360, step=1
                 )
)
```